# IF statement in a WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Would it be possible to create an IF statement in a WHERE clause, I would need something like this in order to filter a certain product.

For example if product 005 has a ranking of 100 or less than the product should not show up in my query results

For example...

```
SELECT b.id, b.rank 
FROM b_products b 
WHERE IF(b.id = '005' AND b.rank < 100, b.id != '005')
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible to do what you need using just "regular" `WHERE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [IF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function expects three arguments, not two:

> IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)
>
> If expr1 is TRUE (expr1 <> 0 and expr1 <> NULL) then IF() returns
>   expr2; otherwise it returns expr3. IF() returns a numeric or string
>   value, depending on the context in which it is used.

However, you haven't described anything that cannot be accomplished with a proper boolean expression:

```
SELECT b.id, b.rank 
FROM b_products b 
WHERE b.id<>'005'
OR (b.id='005' AND b.rank<100)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
WHERE (b.id = '005' AND b.rank >= 100) OR b.id != '005'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify else part in query:

```
SELECT b.id, b.rank 
FROM b_products b 
WHERE IF(b.id = '005' AND b.rank < 100, b.id != '005', else condition)
```

Answer (score 0):

The conditions are directly evaluated in the `WHERE` clause as:

```
SELECT b.id, b.rank 
FROM b_products b 
WHERE NOT (b.id = '005' AND b.rank < 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need an OR clause.

```
SELECT 
    b.id, 
    b.rank 
FROM 
    b_products b 
WHERE 
   (b.id = '005' AND b.rank < 100)
or 
    b.id <> '005'
```